# Extract text from class 'bs4.element.Tag' beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following text in a `class 'bs4.element.Tag'` object:

```
<span id="my_rate">264.46013</span>
```

How do I strip the value of 264.46013 and get rid of the junk before and after the value?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175190/get-value-of-span-tag-using-beautifulsoup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120802/extract-text-between-two-different-tags-beautiful-soup) but I am unable to use the `text.split()` methods etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow,  however, if you are using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<span id="my_rate">264.46013</span>'

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
value = soup.select_one('span[id="my_rate"]').get_text()
print(value)
```

Result:

```
264.46013
```